# how to import static resources in front page with spring boot and thymeleaf when use @PathVariable

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, frontend, thymeleaf

When I just used  **@RequestMapping** like below, I can get the html renders well

```
@RequestMapping("/demo")
    public String news() {
        return "demo";
    }
```

But when I add the param **@PathVariable("docid")**, it lost all the static resources.

```
@RequestMapping("/single/{docid}")
public String single( @PathVariable("docid") String docid) {
    return "demo";
}
```

In browser console, it said **failed to load resource: the server responded with a ststus of 404()**.

I use [localhost:8080/single/123](http://localhost:8080/demo) to launch the page, it will have the **demo.html** without any static resources, but when I use [localhost:8080/demo](http://localhost:8080/single/123), it works well.

I change the import statement to th:src="@{/js/my.js}", it still search the static resource from the **localhost:8080/single/js/my.js**, what should I do?

Ps: I use Thymeleaf for template.

Comment: When you are sending the request from browser, are you sending some value for "docid" ? Since docid is part of the endpoint URL, and if you don't specify any value for docid, you will get 404 error.

Comment: what URL you are using to launch the page, you should try something like: http://<domain>:port/demo/123 where 123 is your docid

Comment: I use http://localhost:8080/single/123 to  launch the page, it will have the **demo.html** without any static resources, but when I use  http://localhost:8080/demo, it works well.

Comment: Why in the first case you mapping starts with the `/` but in the second case it doesn't?

Comment: At first, they all have the `/`, after I google the problem, I thought it maybe the reason. But it not.

Comment: Does the second one works if you remove your path variable?

Comment: Yes, it works. And it is totally same with the first one.

Comment: Can you try using a string value like: http://host:port/single/test

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue, it works perfectly for me. Is these two methods in the same controller class? Where is your demo.html located.

Comment: Also I can say that the problem isn't with the static resources. If the controller isn't able to find static resources you would get `type=Internal Server Error, status=500 `.  In your case you are getting 404, which means that the mapping for `/single/{docid}` isn't created.

Comment: Did you mean  this `public String single() ` ? It will also have a **demo.html** without any static resource

Comment: Are both of these methods located in the same `@Controller` class?

Comment: I think I found the problem. I import the static resource like this `href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css"`, so it can't work when use PathVariable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, I changed all the import statement in `th:fragment` to absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

Use the URL as http://host:port/single/1001, and there is no reason you should get 404. Make sure you are using a value of docid in the path (URL).